# how to prevent input type file from accepting some inputs on change function

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, html, django

I'm working on a project and I need the user to upload only pdf files.

I'm trying to do this in the front-end so whenever the input detects a file type that is not a pdf should reject it. Everything seems correct. However, when I hover over the input it shows me that the wrong file is uploaded. So what should I do?

```js
function changeName(elem) {
  $("input[type='file']").
  elem.on("change", function() {

    var fileName = elem.val().split("\\").pop();
    var fileExtension = elem.val().split(".").pop();
    if (fileExtension === "pdf") {
      elem.siblings(".Syllabus").text(fileName);

    } else {
      elem.siblings(".Syllabus").val('');
      elem.siblings(".Syllabus").text('...');
      alert('Only PDF files are accepted');
    }

  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="Syllabus fileReset">...</label>
<input type="file" accept="application/pdf" name="file1" onClick="changeName($(this));" required class="upload-button removable" />
```

Comment: What's to stop me from renaming my pdf as a txt file and uploading it?  Extension is not the correct way to do this.

Comment: For a feedback to the user it is fine. Server testing is of course needed. See my answer for a client side validation that gives immediate feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works better than what you posted

```js
$("input[type='file']").on("change", function(e) {
  var elem = $(this);
  elem.siblings(".Syllabus").text("...")
  var fileName = elem.val().split("\\").pop();
  var fileExtension = elem.val().split(".").pop();
  
  if (fileExtension !== "pdf") {
    elem.siblings(".Syllabus").text('Only PDF files are accepted')
    elem.replaceWith(elem.val('').clone(true));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="Syllabus fileReset">...</label>
<input type="file" accept="application/pdf" name="file1" required class="upload-button removable" />
```